# Need help with REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a data column that contains a substring similar to this:

```
'This is a string with ID=123 contained inside'
```

i need to replace the `ID=123` with another fixed string say `ID=1`

i have a working REPLACE call that swaps out the values correctly, but this only works on a known original id number.  I can extend to make it work when the number of digits are known by using some substr magic, however, the id number may have an arbitrary number of digits, so i'm thinking regex.

any help with the regex magix to grab the entire `ID=999` substring no matter how many digits would be very helpful.

thanks

Comment: Could you search for the `ID=` instead? Then you don't need a regular expression.

Comment: yes i can search for the ID= but then i also need to replace an arbitrary number of following digits with the digits I know. - this is where i think the regex is needed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try searching for

`ID=\d*`

If you need to keep the first digit, try searching for

`ID=(\d)\d*`

and replace with

`ID=$1`

Comment: thanks - this seems to swap out the first digit with my new digit.  so if i started with ID=123 and replaced with 9 then i get ID=923.  Seems close, but how do you get all following digits?

Comment: ok i just tried with ID=\d(9) - which seemed to stop at the first non digit and give what i wanted...  the 9 part seems arbitrary, but this is way better than what i was doing before.

Comment: lol - one more followup - the * works great - i read right past that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try \d+ and move the grouping to surround the entire clause:

```
select regexp_replace('This is a string with ID=123 contained inside', 'ID=(\d+)', 'ID=456') rep from dual;

 REP                                           
 --------------------------------------------- 
 This is a string with ID=456 contained inside
```